# Flutter Popup Widget in a Provider - What context to pop it closed?

Tags: flutter, dart, popupwindow, flutter-change-notifier

I have a ChangeNotifierProvider class that provides a popup to its Consumer Widgets. The popup function called "showPopup" contains a raised button which when pressed, logs the user in with Google, fetches their information, posts it to a mysql database and saves it to a shared preferences file.

I'm using the provider class in order to access the change notifier because I need to immediately notify other pages as soon as shared preferences is updated with the logged-in user information.

After login, I'd like the popup to automatically close. Unfortunately, the code I'm trying to use won't work - there's a red line under the word "context". Presumably, it's because the popup is being called from a different page.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

What can I put for "context"? Or is there any other way I can get this popup to automatically close immediately after the user has logged in?

Here's the code;

```
class SocialProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  final SocialLogin socialLogin = SocialLogin();

  static const GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

  SocialUser currentUser;
  String currentname;
  String currentavatar;
  String currentemail;
  bool currentlogged;

  void socState() {
    socialLogin.setConfig(SocialConfig(
      googleWebClientId: GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
    ));
  }

  Future<void> logInGoogle() async {
    try {
      socState();
      currentUser = await socialLogin.logInGoogle();
      currentavatar = currentUser.pictureUrl;
      currentname = currentUser.name;
      currentemail = currentUser.email;
      currentlogged = true;
      postSocialData(currentUser.name, currentUser.email, currentavatar);

      savePreferences(
        currentname: currentUser.name,
        currentemail: currentUser.email,
        currentlogged: true,
      );

      Navigator.pop(context);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  savePreferences({String currentname, String currentavatar, String currentemail, bool currentlogged}) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('currentname', currentname);
    prefs.setString('currentavatar', currentavatar);
    prefs.setString('currentemail', currentemail);
    prefs.setBool('currentlogged', currentlogged);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  loadPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String currentname = prefs.getString('currentname');
    String currentavatar = prefs.getString('currentavatar');
    String currentemail = prefs.getString('currentemail');
    bool currentlogged = prefs.getBool('currentlogged');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  showPopup(BuildContext context, Widget widget, String title,
      {BuildContext popupContext}) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      PopupLayout(
        top: 30,
        left: 30,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 50,
        child: PopupContent(
          content: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            body: widget,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget popupBody() {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                    onPressed: logInGoogle,
                    child: Text('Log in with Google'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's where the popup is called from within the build of a Stateful Widget;

```
child: new FlatButton(
               onPressed: () {
                 socialProvider.loadPreferences();
                      if (socialProvider.currentlogged != true) {
                   socialProvider.showPopup(context, socialProvider.popupBody(), 'Cancel Login');
                 } else {
                 switch (_currentStatus) {
                   case RecordingStatus.Initialized:
                     {
                       _start();
                       break;
                     }
                   case RecordingStatus.Recording:
                     {
                       _pause();
                       break;
                     }
                   case RecordingStatus.Paused:
                     {
                       _resume();
                       break;
                     }
                   case RecordingStatus.Stopped:
                     {
                       _init();
                       break;
                     }
                   default:
                     break;
                 }
               }//switch end
               },
               child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                 child: _buildText(_currentStatus),
               ),
               color: Color(0xffb79eb5).withOpacity(.75),
             ),
```

Comment: why dont you pass  `context ` from `showPopup` to `popupBody` to `logInGoogle` ?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Why do you return an entirely new widget in popupBody? Can't you just call Navigator.popUntil() to return back to the homepage? Can you show where the popupBody is used?

Comment: Does this help? I've edited the original post to show the code from where the popup is called from within a Stateful Widget.

Comment: Navigator.popUntil() seems to want a parameter. TBH I don't understand popups or context very well. Any chance of some example code?

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did in the end;

```
Future<void> logInGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      socState();
      currentUser = await socialLogin.logInGoogle();
  
  currentname = currentUser.name;
  currentavatar = currentUser.pictureurl; 
  currentemail = currentUser.email;
  currentlogged = true;
  postSocialData(currentUser.name, currentUser.email, currentavatar);

  savePreferences(
    currentname: currentUser.name,
    currentavatar: currentUser.pictureUrl,
    currentemail: currentUser.email,
    currentlogged: true,
  );
  Navigator.pop(context);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

And for the popup code;

```
showPopup(BuildContext context, Widget widget, String title,
      {BuildContext popupContext}) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      PopupLayout(
        top: 100,
        left: 60,
        right: 60,
        bottom: 100,
        child: PopupContent(
          content: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            body: widget,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



   Widget popupBody(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                    onPressed: () => logInGoogle(context),
                    child: Text('Log in with Google'),
                  )
        ],
      ),
    ),
   
    ],
  ),
  ),
    );
   }
```